# compile/make ffmpeg without man pags

Tags: heroku, ffmpeg, buildpack

I am installing ffmpeg on heroku (ubuntu) with enable-ssl via a build-pack. I am able to build it all the way up to these errors:

```
install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/share/man/man1/ffmpeg.1': Read-only file system
...
install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/share/man/man1/ffmpeg-filters.1': Read-only file system
make: *** [install-man] Error 1
```

I do not have write access to any directory outside of /app. I have tried compiling with `--mandir=/app/vendor/` but that seems to be ignored.

Is there any way to build ffmpeg without the man pages or just have them installed else where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually if your build has gotten to the install step, you should already have the binary for ffmpeg. Build process makes it in the local directory before attempting to move the binary and manuals to the system locations.

Comment: Oh! I had thought it must have finalized the build but I never bothered to check the current dir. Thanks!